# dotnetnuke 6 database configuration from sql server 2008 r2

Tags: dotnetnuke-6

i am facing problem to install dotnetnuke 6 in my local system. i am getting error on database section please provide me the proper step to install database in dot net nuke .

```
Connection Error(s):
Index #: 0
Source: .Net SqlClient Data Provider
Class: 11
Number: 4060
Message: Invalid Database

Index #: 1
Source: .Net SqlClient Data Provider
Class: 14
Number: 18456
Message: Sql login failed
```

Answer (score 1):

You must create the database in SQL Server first.

Then, give the Service Account you are using for DNN permissions to that database.

The Connection properties are in the web.config.